# mongoDB aggregate $sum all nested fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the nested fields for many ingredients and would like to add all the corresponding fields

```
nutrients: {
    vitaminB: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    vitaminC: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    //more
```

I have the following code

```
Ingredient.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { _id: { $in: ingredientIds } },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        sums: { $sum: '$nutrients' },
      },
    },
  ]);
  console.log(stats[0].sums);
```

which outputs a 0. However it works if i specify a nested field for example `$nutrients.vitaminC`

I would expect `sums` to be an object with the sums of each nested field

Comment: As you've discovered, using any data as field names will complicate queries.  If possible, changing your data model to something like, `"nutrients": [ {"name": "vitaminB", "amount": 100}, ... ]` will probably make future queries less complicated.

Comment: You're right I should be doing that! Though in that case I'd have to create a separate match for each of those names, if I have 100 different nutrients wouldn't that mean 100 queries as well? (I'm genuinely asking I'm new with mongoDB)

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about _"would like to add all the corresponding fields"_.  Would you show a slightly expanded example collection and also the desired output given that example collection?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the approach that you've attempted. It's also unclear if you would like to compute this sum per document or if you do want a single total across all matching documents.

If you want the former, then you should replace the `$group` with a `$addFields` stage. This will evaluate the sum per document. One way to do that is to leverage `$reduce` and convert the structure of the field to something more amenable to the processing that you're interested in. For example:

```
{
    "$addFields": {
      "sums": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": "$nutrients"
          },
          initialValue: 0,
          "in": {
            $sum: [
              "$$this.v",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HvwlprXxUEk)

If you do want the latter behavior asked about above, then append a subsequent `$group` to pull the values together from across the documents:

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sums": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": "$nutrients"
          },
          initialValue: 0,
          "in": {
            $sum: [
              "$$this.v",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      sums: {
        $sum: "$sums"
      },
      
    },
    
  }
]
```

[Playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/quY_HDH1TuJ)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not looking for either of those sorry if I wasn't clear. Instead I'd like the sum over many matching documents for each name field, in your example `vitaminB:6` and `vitaminC:9`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  The important step, as noted in the solution above, is to use `$objectToArray` to turn lvals (e.g. `vitaminB:value`) into rvals (e.g. `k:vitaminB,v:value`:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {"$project": {"X": {"$objectToArray": "$nutrients"}}},
    {"$unwind": "$X"},

    // Not exactly sure if "default" is the number that should be summed
    // but if not, just change to the correct one.  Note the dotpath to
    // the field via the `v` field created by $objectToArray:
    {"$group": {_id: "$X.k", sums: {$sum: "$X.v.default"}}}
]);
```

Yields:

```
{
  _id: 'vitaminC',
  sums: 6
}
{
  _id: 'vitaminK',
  sums: 5
}
{
  _id: 'vitaminB',
  sums: 4
}
etc.
```